# SMS options for android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a code that uses sms operation. Here's the code I have:-

```
public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"+data.phno));
            //intent.putExtra("address", data.phno);
            intent.putExtra("sms_body","Some Stuff.");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

In this case, the user is sent to a compose sms screen. I would like to know whether there any other way I can send sms to the user, without prompting the user of the android device and also is it possible to know whether sms is sent or not for the above case and also the case I wanted to know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just use SmsManager, which invisibly sends an SMS

Answer (score 0):

```
SMSSender smsSender = new SMSSender( this );
smsSender.sendSMS( phoneNumber, message );
```